# Invariant differential forms?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, connections, principal-bundles, gauge-theory

In the first page of the paper "On the spaces of maps inducing isomorphic connections" by T.R. Ramadas, one can read that the automorphisms of a connection $\nabla$ on a principal $G$-bundle $\pi:P \longrightarrow M$, denoted by $\mathsf{Aut}(\nabla)$, are those $G$-equivariant maps $P \longrightarrow P$ which cover the identity of $M$ and leave the connection $\nabla$ invariant. 
Now, my question is: what does "leave invariant" mean here? Take a map $f$ in $\mathsf{Aut}(\nabla)$. Does this mean that the pull-back $f^*\nabla = \nabla$?

Comment: A connection on a principal bundle can equivalently be characterised by its horizontal distribution $H$, i.e. $TP=H\oplus V$ where $V=\ker (d\pi:TP\to TM)$. One geometric way to think about this statement is that we should have $f^*H=H$. Equivalently, a connection is described by a $1$-form $\omega$ (which you call $\nabla$ but this is unusual for principal bundles), and then you would require $f^*\omega=\omega$.